# ISO-8859-1 to UTF8 conversion

Tags: utf-8, go, iso-8859-1

The following snippet converts `ISO-8859-1` encoded text to `UTF8`. I don't exactly understand what's going on here. Can someone explain why this works?

```
var utf8Buf bytes.Buffer
for _, b := range iso8859Slice {
  utf8Buf.WriteRune(rune(b))
}
utf8Str := utf8Buf.String()
```

Comment: Check out https://code.google.com/p/go-charset/ if you want to do this properly or for different characters sets than latin1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop takes each byte of the iso8859Str slice assuming it is of type `[]byte`

Because iso-8859-1 is incorperated as the first 256 code points of Unicode, you have no need of actual conversion from iso-8859-1 to Unicode.

However, what you need to do is to UTF-8 encode the Unicode rune. This is done by Buffer.WriteRune()

> WriteRune appends the UTF-8 encoding of Unicode code point r to the buffer

Comment: Yes, it's not a string it's a byte slice - my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

First: It **does not work** if `iso8859Str` is of type string!

But if  `iso8859Str` is of type []byte your `range` clause iterates over bytes and
that is how unicode was designed: Bytes in ISO 8859-1 correspond to the same unicode codepoint.

Comment: Your answer is a bit confusing as-is; you might want to add a paragraph about UTF-8 where this does not directly hold.